# The $k[X]$-module and linear operator correspondence

Tags: linear-algebra

A standard concept used in basic linear algebra is that a linear operator $T:V\to V$ on a $k$-vector space, induces a $k[X]$-module structure on $V$ by setting $Xv:=Tv$ for all vectors $v\in V$. This also works for endomorphisms over of modules over any commutative ring, but all the applications I've seen always need that the vector space/module is finite dimensional/finitely generated. The results that I've seen, which can be derived from this line of thinking are the following:

- Rational and Jordan Decomposition of Linear Operators/Matrices
- Proof of Cayley-Hamilton (for modules over commutative rings)

The upside of using this approach has been that the proofs are conceptually much simpler and don't require juggling with matrices, sums and other nasty things.

**My question is the following:** Besides the results that I wrote above, what other results from basic linear algebra are useful to view through this correspondence? I've noticed that understanding a result through this lens has typically deepened my understanding of what's going on and why a result should be true.

Comment: One advantage of the module point of view is that the main theorems of linear algebra are a consequence of the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over principal ideal domains, which also implies the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups. It's nice to see both theories are related.

Comment: May I ask: what texts have you learned these things from so far? I was going to say that I think Jacobson's Basic Algebra books take this approach, and you might find something there.

Comment: I've looked at Dummit and Foote as well as Lang's Algebra. However, these tools are usually used when they are very much needed and when there aren't slick elementary proofs i.e. when doing Rational/Jordan decomposition. What I was really looking for if there are enlightening ways of seeing many simpler results through this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See "A Polynomial Approach to Linear Algebra" by Paul A. Fuhrmann for waht is essentially an entire text on the topic.